# What is the Net Standard Library for Plugin.GoogleAnalytics

Tags: xamarin

What is the Net Standard Library for Plugin.GoogleAnalytics? I'm converting Portable Class Libraries to Net Standard ones, couldn't find the equivalent of this package.

Below is the IAnalytics interface for this library.

```
    void SendEvent(string category, string action, string label, long value);

    void SendEvent(string category, string action, string label, int value);

    void SendEvent(string category, string action, string label);

    void SendEvent(string category, string action);

    void SendException(string description, bool isFatal);

    void SendException(Exception exception, bool isFatal);

    void SendView(string screenName);

    void SetEndSession(bool value);

    void SetStartSession(bool value);
```

Comment: Isn't Firebase the new entry point for any analytics project ? I'm not sure. If that's the case, then I guess Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, firebase is the way to go for analytics. I'm posting a POC that I did using firebase for analytics,  https://github.com/SudhersonV/Xamarin/tree/develop/FirebasePOC